CODEIGNITER: I can't input/search any words and not showing the datavalue from my database using select2
Selection of Items/Search of items
I have problem inputting a words i can't input or click in the search box or maybe i have error in my code or in my script.
My View:
<select type="text" name="protitle" class="form-control" id="recipient-name123" required>
     <option>Select Bus</option>
</select>

My script:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryvalidate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#recipient-name123').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '<?php echo base_url("projects/searchbus"); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function(params) {
                    return {
                        protitle: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function(data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.cat_name + " - " + item.cat_busnum,
                                id: item.cat_name + " - " + item.cat_busnum
                            };
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            minimumInputLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>

This is my Model:
public function search_bus($protitle) {
        $this->db->like('cat_name', $protitle);
        $this->db->or_like('cat_busnum', $protitle);
        $query = $this->db->get('assets_category');
        return $query->result();
    }

This is my controller:
public function searchbus() 
{
  $protitle = $this->input->post('protitle');
  $data['results'] = $this->project_model->search_bus($protitle);
  $this->load->view('backend/All_Projects', $data);
}

I just want to search in the select/dropdown and show the data from my database. Do have any suggestion to remove, edit, or add to my code to work? Thank you!

Does your select2 happen to be inside a Bootstrap modal? That can also cause you not being able to click in its input box in certain browsers. If so, try setting the dropdownParent as explained here: https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems

from the select2 docs: Keep in mind that results should be passed as an array of objects. - From your controller, you are not sending anything similar back to your Ajax function, how should ´processResults´ read your attempt with this view file?

I think the mistake came from your Model, you must return a JSON format element.
Try :
public function search_bus($protitle) {
    $this->db->like('cat_name', $protitle);
    $this->db->or_like('cat_busnum', $protitle);
    $query = $this->db->get('assets_category');
    return json_encode($query->result());
}

